# Error inserting embedded documents into MongoDB using Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala

I use mongo-scala-driver 2.9.0 and this is a function saving a user's Recommendation List to MongoDB. The argument **streamRecs** is An Array of (productId:Int, score:Double). Now i want to insert a document consisting of an ***useId*** and its  relevant reconmendation list ***recs***. However, there is an error in the line `val doc:Document = Document("userId" -> userId,"recs"->recs)`. Does anyone know what goes wrong?

```
  def saveRecsToMongoDB(userId: Int, streamRecs: Array[(Int, Double)])(implicit mongoConfig: MongoConfig): Unit ={
    val streamRecsCollection = ConnHelper.mongoClient.getDatabase(mongoConfig.db).getCollection(STREAM_RECS_COLLECTION)
    streamRecsCollection.findOneAndDelete(equal("userId",userId))
    val recs: Array[Document] = streamRecs.map(item=>Document("productId"->item._1,"score"->item._2))
    val doc:Document = Document("userId" -> userId,"recs"->recs)
    streamRecsCollection.insertOne(doc)
  }
```

the document i want to insert into MongoDB is like this(it means an
 user and his recommendation products and scores):

```
{
  "_id":****,
  "userId":****,
  "recs":[
         {
          "productId":****,
          "score":****
         },
         {
          "productId":****,
          "score":****
         },
         {
          "productId":****,
          "score":****
         },
         {
          "productId":****,
          "score":****
         }                                                                                              
         ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating a BSON document, declare the Bson type explicitly for each value in the key/value pair, like so:

```
/* Compose Bson document */
val document = Document(
   "email" -> BsonString("email@domain.com"),
   "token" -> BsonString("some_random_string"),
   "created" -> BsonDateTime(org.joda.time.DateTime.now.toDate)
)
```

To see an example, please check https://code.linedrop.io/articles/Storing-Object-in-MongoDB.